# Ubuntu Core install and Launchpad id with dash

Tags: system-installation, mount, systemd, ubuntu-core, username

I have just installed Ubuntu Core 16 on a Raspberry Pi 3.

This is a suggestion for the Ubuntu Core installer but I do not know where to place it so I state it here.

Since my Launchpad id has a dash in it and the installer just used that id as user name on the device it was very inconvenient to create matching unit file names for mounting external USB disks since the name should match the mount location and it already requires a substitution of / with - in the file name.

For example mounting the disk on

> /home/igor-lopez/backup

needed a unit file name of:

> home-igor\x2dlopez-backup.mount

hence to create such a file one has to escape the backslash

```
$ touch home-igor\\x2dlopez-backup.mount
```

I think it would have been easier to replace a dash in the Launchpad id with an underscore when creating the user during install.